# Assign string value to InnerText XML attribute value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I am trying to extract the first word from a string into the `firstName` element. All remaining words should go in the `lastName` element.

**Example**

`ClientName = Stev Finance Company`

Here `Stev` is the `firstName` and `Finance Company` is the `lastName`.

Here is my code, where `doc` is an XML document:

```
// XML construction – no issue here 
XmlDocument Mainroot = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = Mainroot.CreateElement("Parent");
XmlElement firstName = Mainroot.CreateElement("FirstName");
XmlElement lastName = Mainroot.CreateElement("LastName");

var clientname = XmlHelper.getString(doc, "//BusinessClient/ClientName"); 
var firstName = clientname.Split(' ');
var lastName = clientname.Split(' ', (char)StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

firstName.InnerText = firstName; // Getting an error: "Cannot Convert string[] to string"
lastName.InnerText = lastName; // Getting an error: "Cannot Convert string[] to string"
```

Please let me know why I am getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are correct; you have two issues here:

1. You are reusing the `firstName` identifier for an `XmlElement` and a string array returned from the `string.Split()` method.
2. You are attempting to assign a string array to the `XmlElement.innerText` property, but it expects a string.

To fix these issues, rename or inline one of the variables and change the type of the values you are assigning to `string` instead of `string[]`. You can achieve this by using `string.Join()` to concatenate the values in the string array back into a string. In the example below, the values are joined with a space and the first word is skipped (since it was used as the first name).

```
// XML construction – no issue here 
XmlDocument Mainroot = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = Mainroot.CreateElement("Parent");
XmlElement firstName = Mainroot.CreateElement("FirstName");
XmlElement lastName = Mainroot.CreateElement("LastName");

var clientname = XmlHelper.getString(doc, "//BusinessClient/ClientName"); 

// Set the value of this element to the first word in the client name.
firstName.innerText = clientname.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();

// Set the value of this element to the rest of the word(s) in the client name.
lastName.innerText = string.Join(" ", clientname.Split(' ', (char)StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , here again FirstOrDefault(); and Skip(1) not found - this is error I am getting

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` and `Skip()` are available in the [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-5.0) library. Add them to your project by including `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

When you are replacing `var` with the explicit type you can see that `firstName` is `string`... and String doen't have a `innerText` Property but the provided code looks incomplete, because you should get an error if that block is all in one method because of double instatiation.

Comment: Please let me know how do I achieve this, I need to extract FirstName and last from ClientName and then I need to insert back in new XML tag

Comment: then you should read the documentation of XmlDocument: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-5.0 where are here for HELP, not doing your job ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because, 'Split' method returns array of strings. If you want to get only one string, try this:
var firstName = clientname.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
var lastName = clientname.Split(' ', (char)StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault();

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thank you for the response, FirstOrDefault() Property is not present in "clientname.Split(' ')." , kindly let me know how do I do that

Comment: Add 'using System.Linq'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind response